# How to get Object Id from html back to the Controller MVC c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

JQuery:

```
$("#shoppingCart").droppable(
    {
        accept: ".block",
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            $(this).append(droppedItem);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Social/AddSocialToList/' + $(ui.draggable).attr("id"),
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
    );
});
```

Controller:

```
[Route("socialmedia")]
public class SocialController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route("AddSocialToList")]
    public IActionResult AddSocialToList(string _id)
    {
        TwitterModel tm = new TwitterModel { Key = _id, ScreenName = "Screen1" };

        _db2._SocialList.Add(tm);
        _db2.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Social");
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="imageboundary">
<div id="shoppingCart" style="background:#00ffff; width:200px; padding:10px; margin:10px;">

        <ul id="cart"></ul>
        @foreach (var socialList in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_SocialList", socialList)
        }
    </div>
```

```
<article class="blog-post" style="display: inline" >
    <ul class="links">
        <li>
            <img alt="Widget View" src="~/images/thumbnailtwitter.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
            @Model.Key
            @Model.ScreenName
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I am new to MVC I have done serval tutorials. I have List of objects coming from a database successfully through the controller So I would like to drag and drop a copy of the object from the draggable div into a droppable. But I would like to add that object to the database. But stays on the same page. When I send the ID across to the controller to query it is saying:

jquery-3.1.1.min.js:11 POST http://localhost:61615/Social/AddSocialToList/undefined 404 (Not Found)

I would like to take the database key (Model.Key) from the draggable object and pass it through the jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your droppable item "article" does not have an attribute named "id".

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<article data-key="@Model.Key" class="blog-post" style="display: inline" >
<ul class="links">
    <li>
        <img alt="Widget View" src="~/images/thumbnailtwitter.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
        @Model.Key
        @Model.ScreenName
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#shoppingCart").droppable(
{
    accept: ".block",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        var droppedItem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        $(this).append(droppedItem);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Social/AddSocialToList/' + $(ui.draggable).data("key"),
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The Call still fails with:


jquery-3.1.1.min.js:11 POST http://localhost:61615/Social/AddSocialToList/undefined 404 (Not Found)


I put a break point in the controller method and it did not reach

Comment: What's the name of your Controller?

Comment: SocialController but I have [Route("socialmedia")] above the class and   [HttpPost, Route("SaveSearch")] above the method

Comment: Try to delete the Route-Attribute above the controller, because in your ajax post you call '/Social/AddSocialToList/' instead of '/socialmedia/AddSocialToList/'.

Comment: Thanks. I have managed to get The call to the controller now by doing that but it's still undefine

Comment: Did you apply the jquery and html?

Comment: Summary:

I was Targeting the wrong class but your solutions works.


Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134183/discussion-between-decoder94-and-den-ko).